# How do I navigate to bing.com and enter a search text using the chrome console?

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code.
It is resulting in unexpected behaviour.
It navigates to bing.com but it does not fill in the text field. Also, I have noticed that the console get cleared after navigating to a new webpage.

```
window.location = "https://www.bing.com";
window.onload = function(){
    var editSearch = document.getElementById("sb_form_q");
    editSearch.value = "Quux";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is only valid for the current page you are on. When you are executing code from DevTools console, you are executing code on that page itself. So, when you navigate to another page using `window.location` you loose the `onload` handler you have defined.

To add handlers to a different page, it must be connected to your page (the parent) in some way, like an iframe or a popup.

```
ifrm = document.getElementById('frame');
ifrm.src = 'http://example.com';
ifrm.contentWindow.onload = function () {
    // do something here with
    // ifrm.contentWindow.document.getElementById('form')
}
```

Comment: Your answer seems to provide information that will actually solve my problem. Please give me an example of an iframe or popup with bing.com and my search text.

Comment: Actually never mind. I have just read its documentation on w3schools. It is easy as heck.

Answer (score 5):

You are binding the `onload` function to the existing `window` object.

When the browser loads the new page, it will make a new `window` object which won't have your property set on it.

JavaScript run in one page (even when you are running it through developer tools) can't persist variables onto a different page.

(Storage mechanisms like localStorage and cookies are available, but you would need code in the subsequent page to look for them).

Answer (score 1):

As @Quentin said.

**But you can do another way like ..**

```
var keyword = "Quux";
window.location = "https://www.bing.com/search?q="+keyword;
```